# I am totally dead of this issue: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: invalidParameter]

Tags: c#

I am totally new of MONO.

I created one new Window Forms Application, without any coding. then move to MonoDevelop @ Fedora 18 (i installed latest monodevelop in Fedora with yum install monodevelop), Compile is fine, but when try to run, it reports below error: (Do i need to install other patch or something else for this?)

```
System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (status=System.Drawing.Status.InvalidParameter) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/gdipFunctions.cs:220
System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (width=0, height=0, format=System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Bitmap.cs:97
System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (original={System.Drawing.Bitmap}, width=0, height=0) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Bitmap.cs
System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (original={System.Drawing.Bitmap}, newSize={{Width=0, Height=0}}) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Bitmap.cs
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DefineCursor (bitmap={System.Drawing.Bitmap}, mask={System.Drawing.Bitmap}, cursor_pixel={Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]}, mask_pixel={Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]}, xHotSpot=7, yHotSpot=7) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/XplatUIX11.cs:3023
System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DefineCursor (bitmap={System.Drawing.Bitmap}, mask={System.Drawing.Bitmap}, cursor_pixel={Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]}, mask_pixel={Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]}, xHotSpot=7, yHotSpot=7) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/XplatUI.cs:567
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.CreateCursor (stream={System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream}) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Cursor.cs:110
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor..ctor (type={System.Windows.Forms.Cursor}, resource="NWSE.cur") in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Cursor.cs:160
System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.get_SizeNWSE () in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Cursors.cs:311
System.Windows.Forms.SizeGrip..ctor (CapturedControl={LinuxTest.Form1, Text: }) in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/SizeGrip.cs:47
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.CreateScrollbars () in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ScrollableControl.cs:1127
System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ScrollableControl.cs:318
System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/ContainerControl.cs
System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/Managed.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/Form.cs
LinuxTest.Form1..ctor () in /home/GTC/MyProject/LinuxTest/LinuxTest/Form1.cs
LinuxTest.Program.Main () in /home/GTC/MyProject/LinuxTest/LinuxTest/Program.cs:18
```

Comment: `System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (width=0, height=0` look suspicious for size of the image... Also posting code that shows the issue is a good idea for questions on SO.

Comment: actually i didn't add any code. all the code were generated by Visual Studio @ windows.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LinuxTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running simple winforms application on Mono for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674759/running-simple-winforms-application-on-mono-for-arm)