# Mono libgdiplus crash on Armv7 Debian 9 build

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, debian, armv7

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a winforms application running with Mono version 4.6.2 (from apt) on Debian 9, Kernel 4.9 with Armv7. I have also tried with Mono 5.18 from the [Mono install guide](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian), but I had the same error. This project was previously running on Debian 7 with a 3.0 Kernel and it ran fine.

**Any time I try to run my application I see the following error:**

> Unhandled Exception:
>       System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]
>         at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status status) [0x0009b] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format) [0x00017] in
>   <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.Drawing.Image original, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) [0x00000] in
>   <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.Drawing.Image original, System.Drawing.Size newSize) [0x00010] in
>   <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (System.Drawing.Image,System.Drawing.Size)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DefineCursor (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap, System.Drawing.Bitmap mask,
>   System.Drawing.Color cursor_pixel, System.Drawing.Color mask_pixel,
>   System.Int32 xHotSpot, System.Int32 yHotSpot) [0x0004e] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DefineCursor (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap, System.Drawing.Bitmap mask,
>   System.Drawing.Color cursor_pixel, System.Drawing.Color mask_pixel,
>   System.Int32 xHotSpot, System.Int32 yHotSpot) [0x00000] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.CreateCursor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00058] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Cursor..ctor (System.Type type, System.String resource) [0x00021] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.get_SizeNWSE () [0x0001a] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.SizeGrip..ctor (System.Windows.Forms.Control CapturedControl) [0x00006] in
>   :0 
>         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.SizeGrip:.ctor (System.Windows.Forms.Control)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.CreateScrollbars () [0x000c2] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x000b0] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x0000e] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00012] in :0 
>         at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <6f95f68c33fe4d859a6075a68bb5c47f>:0 
>         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
>         at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00000] in <6f95f68c33fe4d859a6075a68bb5c47f>:0 
>       [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status:
>   InvalidParameter]
>         at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status status) [0x0009b] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat format) [0x00017] in
>   <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.Drawing.Image original, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height) [0x00000] in
>   <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor (System.Drawing.Image original, System.Drawing.Size newSize) [0x00010] in
>   <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0 
>         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Bitmap:.ctor (System.Drawing.Image,System.Drawing.Size)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.DefineCursor (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap, System.Drawing.Bitmap mask,
>   System.Drawing.Color cursor_pixel, System.Drawing.Color mask_pixel,
>   System.Int32 xHotSpot, System.Int32 yHotSpot) [0x0004e] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.DefineCursor (System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap, System.Drawing.Bitmap mask,
>   System.Drawing.Color cursor_pixel, System.Drawing.Color mask_pixel,
>   System.Int32 xHotSpot, System.Int32 yHotSpot) [0x00000] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.CreateCursor (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00058] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Cursor..ctor (System.Type type, System.String resource) [0x00021] in
>   :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.get_SizeNWSE () [0x0001a] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.SizeGrip..ctor (System.Windows.Forms.Control CapturedControl) [0x00006] in
>   :0 
>         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.SizeGrip:.ctor (System.Windows.Forms.Control)
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.CreateScrollbars () [0x000c2] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x000b0] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor () [0x0000e] in :0 
>         at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00012] in :0 
>         at HelloWorld..ctor () [0x00000] in <6f95f68c33fe4d859a6075a68bb5c47f>:0 
>         at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) HelloWorld:.ctor ()
>         at HelloWorld.Main () [0x00000] in <6f95f68c33fe4d859a6075a68bb5c47f>:0

I originally believed this may be a problem with my application, but I have tried running the following blank winform application (from the [mono website](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/#winforms-hello-world)) and receive the same error.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class HelloWorld : Form
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Application.Run (new HelloWorld ());
    }

    public HelloWorld ()
    {
        Text = "Hello Mono World";
    }
}
```

By looking at the error message and this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674759/running-simple-winforms-application-on-mono-for-arm) it seems to be an issue with loading the cursor, but I'm a bit lost on how exactly I can fix that problem. The post is pretty old and can't seem to find any relevant video drivers to fix the hardware cursor problem. Perhaps I need to make an adjustment to my X11 configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running simple winforms application on Mono for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674759/running-simple-winforms-application-on-mono-for-arm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this resolved by setting up an xorg.conf file with the settings I needed for my video driver. Once I did this mono launched without issue. Below is the configuration I used

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Builtin Default Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Builtin Default fbdev Device 0"
        Driver          "fbdev"
        Option          "fbdev"         "/dev/fb0"
        Option          "Rotate"        "UD"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Builtin Default fbdev Screen 0"
        Device          "Builtin Default fbdev Device 0"
        Monitor         "Builtin Default Monitor"
        DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "Builtin Default Layout"
        Screen          "Builtin Default fbdev Screen 0"
EndSection
```